# Doctest multiple files from one file

Tags: python, testing, doctest

**Project Structure**

```
components/
    A.py
    B.py

run_test.py
```

`A.py` and `B.py` each has some functions with doctest test cases.

How can I run all tests in `A.py` and `B.py` by running only `run_test.py`?

Any other approach to achieve "Run all tests in A.py and B.py` will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2):

Should've read the document more in detail.

1. Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/8471995) answer for importing with path.
2. Using example from doctest document run test

```
import doctest
import importlib.util

# from link

def import_module(name, path):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, path)
    foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
    return foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_modules = [
        ("components.A", "components/A.py"),
        ("components.B", "components/B.py")
    ]
    
    for name, path in test_modules:
        doctest.testmod(import_module(name, path)) # from document
```